# Как заполнить select из json, используя angular?

Tags: jquery, php, select, angularjs

Добрый день.

Как можно из Json внести данные в <select><Option>...</Option></select>, используя angularjs (либо jquery)?

Есть json ответ типа

```
[{"id":"5","Year":"2010"},{"id":"6","Year":"2010"},{"id":"7","Year":"2013"}]
```

Хочу внести его в select.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ng-options**

```
<select ng-model="selected.id" ng-options="item.id as item.Year for item in items">
    <option value=''>Select year</option>
</select>
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/bd3xsh57/)**

---

**option с `ng-repeat`**

```
<select ng-model="selected.id">
    <option value="">Select year</option>
    <option value="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.Year}}</option>
</select>
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/bd3xsh57/1/)**

---

Предпочитать `ng-options` потому, что:

- можно выбрать другие типы, чем `String` (однако когда пишем `value="{{item.id}}"`, тип значения атрибута `value` всегда `String`)
- производительность: не создаёт `scope` для каждого элемента коллекции
- синтакс яснее

Answer (score 2):

Вам никто не мешает написать Ng-repeat внутри блока Select

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="item in data">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

[Пример в плунке](http://plnkr.co/edit/7pimBA?p=preview)